# Get discriminator value from Entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-metadata

I have a TPH (Table per Hierarchy) set up in Entity Framework, where I use a column called `Discriminator` to seperate the different EntityTypes.

I.e. when the Discriminator is 0 the type is `Dog`, if it's 1 it's `Cat` etc

Now I  want to move some code for (mass)-updating from EF to a custom `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

Question:
Is it possible to extract the Discriminator value from the Type through the `MetadataWorkspace` or by some other way?

I'm look for something like `GetDiscriminatorValue<Cat>("ColumnName")`

If not possible: is there another way so I don't have to hardcode those values somewhere in my code?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525953/can-i-access-the-discriminator-value-in-tph-mapping-with-entity-framework-4-ctp5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried yet but it seems that you can get the value (and other non-public properties) using reflection and MetadataWorkSpace. Take a look at this example: http://blog.cincura.net/231942-tph-mapping-discriminator-condition-from-metadataworkspace/

Comment: There is an assumption somewhere that the condition is always a string (while mine was an int), but for the rest it seems to work! :) Thanks!